# не могу понять как правильно написать запрос input в Python

Tags: python

Есть такая функция:

```
def choose_one_file():
    n = input('Какой файл необходимо обработать: ')
     while n.isalpha():
        n = input("Какой файл необходимо обработать: ")
        print('Это число')

    if int(n) in list_files:
        print('Есть такой ключ в словаре')
        return int(n)

    else:
        print('Нет такого ключа в словаре')
        choose_one_file()
```

Ею я хочу получить на выходе число ключа в словаре, который использую в дальнейшем. Ну так вот, всё вроде работает, но если сначала ввести число ключа в справочнике которого нет, то в конечном итоге функция возвращает "None".

Я понимаю, что проблема с рекурсией, но не могу понять что именно не так в моей логике. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему функция ведёт себя таким образом и дайте, пожалуйста, пример того когда, который будет работать.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Я переписал функцию так что бы она работала:

```
def choose_one_file():
    while True:
        input_data = input("Какой файл необходимо обработать: ")
        if not input_data.isnumeric():
            print("Вы ввели не число. Попробуйте снова")
        elif int(input_data) in list_files:
            return input_data
            break
        else:
            print("Ваше число в правильном диапазоне. Попробуйте снова")
```